# What is the best practice for including jQuery ext functions?

Tags: jquery

Currently I have a file that I named JQuery.ext.js which I am including in all of my pages. Inside this file I have numerous functions that do things like the following,

```
(function($) {


    /**
     * Checks to see if a container is empty. Returns true if it is empty
     * @return bool
     */
    $.fn.isEmptyContainer = function() {
        //If there are no children inside the element then it is empty
        return ($(this).children().length <= 0) ? $(this) : false;
    };

    /**
     * Strip html tags from elements
     * @return jQuery
     */
    $.fn.stripHTML = function() {
        var regexp = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/gi;

        //Loop through all elements that were passed in
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regexp, ""));
        });
        return $(this);
    };

    /**
     * This function will check the length of a textarea and not allow the user to go beyond this length.
     * You should use the onkeypress event to trigger this function
     *
     * @param event event This value should always be event when passing it into this function
     * @param maxlength int The maximum amount of character that the user is allowed to type in a textarea
     */
    $.fn.enforceMaxLength = function(event, maxlength) {
        //Only allow the client code to use the onkeypress event
        if(event.type == 'keypress') {
            //If the client code does not pass in a maxlength then set a default value of 255
            var charMax = (!maxlength || typeof(maxlength) != "number") ? 255 : maxlength;

            //If the user is using the backspace character then allow it always
            if(event.which == 8) { return true; }
            //Else enforce the length
            else { return ($(this).val().length <= charMax); }
        }

        //Will only get here if the event type is not keypress
        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Is there another way to do this? or is this the way most people do it?

Thanks for any help, Metropolis

**EDITED**

**Added different plugins to the code and removed the validation plugins**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the scope of those functions.  If you have a **very generic** list of functions that you constantly use in your applications, I would put them in a separate file, and include them when necessary.

But here's a small note: using proper terms, you are actually using plug-ins, not functions, and you are not being compliant with the authoring guide. I don't think this is a major issue though. :)

Also, the functions you sampled from that file seem to serve as validation routines, so I would put them in a separate validation library. Even better, I would use something like jquery-validate and add custom validation methods with $.validator.addMethod().

**Edit**:

As to how exactly I would group jQuery functions/plug-ins, I would do it exactly the same as your example:

```
(function ($) {
   // my list of functions, plug-ins, or classes; as needed by the application
}(jQuery);
```

But I would group them by functionality. For example: if you have validation, formatting, and animation functions/plug-ins, I would create 3 files: jquery.myvalidation.js, jquery.myformatting.js, etc.  The question of when to use a function or a plug-in, depends on whether you need to have access to the "current" jQuery element (use plug-ins), or not (use functions).

The point I'm trying to emphasize here is about grouping things logically, in a modular way to avoid unnecessary coupling and maximize re-use.  When you write a jQuery plug-in, it should deal with a very specific piece of functionality (like the autocomplete, scrollTo, or validate plug-ins)

Comment: Thanks for the help favio. I actually have a lot more than just validation functions here. These just happen to be the first few in that file. You said that I was actually using plugins here, yes I have set them up in the plugin format, but do you think that I should do this a different way? I am going to put some other functions here and remove the validation ones to show you some other functions I need to organize also.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for the help Favio. I believe you helped me understand if I was at least somewhat on the right track for this. I will try to think about this some more and find a way to separate these in a logic manor.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [official plugin authoring guidelines](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).  Also, Mike Alsup detailed a pretty specific and useful development pattern [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern).

Comment: I have already viewed both of those......But those were specifically written for plugins.....I just want to figure out what I should do with these extra functions? Is it ok to have them like this? Or is there a better way to organize this file?